# pass optional parameters to require()

Tags: node.js, node-modules

so, I have this problem - and when I have a problem with JavaScript or node inevitably it is my coding that is the problem ;)

So at the risk of ridicule, this is the problem:

I have a module that has an optional parameter for config

Using the standard pattern, this is what I have:

```
module.exports = function(opts){
    return {
        // module instance
    };
}
```

and in the calling code there is this

```
var foo = require('bar')({option: value})
```

if there are no options to pass, the code looks like this

```
var foo = require('bar')({})
```

which kinda looks ugly

so, I wanted to do this

```
var foo = require('bar')
```

which doesn't work, as the exports is a function call

so, to the meat of the issue

a) is there any way of achieving this lofty goal ?
b) is there a better pattern of passing parameters to a module ?

many thanks - and I hope that once the laughter has passed you will be able to send some help my way :)

Comment: I mean, if your only problem is "it's ugly", you don't have to do it all on one line.

Comment: what can I say ? I want to achieve "zen" in my coding style ;) empty ({}) are just plain ugly. My code should be beautiful ...

Comment: It should also be functional and easy to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of removing the function call completely, you could make the options argument options to remove the need for an empty object:

```
module.exports = function(opts) {
    opts = opts || {};
    return {
        // module instance
    };
}
```

It doesn't completely remove the need for `()` but is better than `({})`.

Answer (score 3):

**tldr**: stick with `require('foo')('bar');`

There's no way to pass additional parameters to `require`. Here's the [source code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/069dd07a1732c6a752773aaed9e8c18ab472375f/lib/module.js#L354), notice how it only takes a single argument:

```
Module.prototype.require = function(path) {
  assert(util.isString(path), 'path must be a string');
  assert(path, 'missing path');
  return Module._load(path, this);
};
```

If you really really really want to avoid `()()`, you could try something like this:

### b.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    x: 'default',
    configure: function (x) {
        this.x = x;
    },
    doStuff: function () {
        return 'x is ' + this.x;
    }
};
```

### a.js

```
'use strict';

var b = require('./b');

// Default config:
console.log(b.doStuff()); // 'x is default'

// Reconfigure:
b.configure(42);

console.log(b.doStuff()); // 'x is 42'
```

But I think it's uglier... stick with the original idea.